# error instantiating BabyAGI agent: can't instantiate abstract class BasePromptTemplate

Tags: agent, langchain, large-language-model

I am attempting to instantiate a BabyAGI agent in Langchain in this way:

```
baby_agi = BabyAGI.from_llm(
    llm=OpenAI(model="text-davinci-003", temperature=0),
    vectorstore=vectorstore,
    verbose=False,
    max_iterations=3,
)
```

The resulting error is:

```
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-86ea8532e15d> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 # create thebabyagi agent
      9 # If max_iterations is None, the agent may go on forever if stuck in loops
---> 10 baby_agi = BabyAGI.from_llm(
     11     llm=OpenAI(model="text-davinci-003", temperature=0),
     12     vectorstore=vectorstore,

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for TaskCreationChain
prompt
  Can't instantiate abstract class BasePromptTemplate with abstract methods format, format_prompt (type=type_error)
```

I did have to correct the import as follows:

```
from langchain_experimental.autonomous_agents import BabyAGI
```

I expected the object to be instantiated, so that I could run the agent thusly:

```
response = baby_agi({"objective": "Plan a trip to Germany."})
```